# Fullcalendar not rendering in dialog

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am using Fullcalendar (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) and trying to get it to display in a dialog.

When I click the button to open the dialog, the dialog appears and calendar renders but it only shows the top left corner of the actual calendar. If I then drag the corners of dialog even literally 1mm the calendar properly and fully renders into the dialog space both horizontally and vertically.

I found a reference on the Fullcalendar site for render which sounds like exactly what I need - it forces the calendar to immediatley render and adjusts it size.

The example on the site (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/display/render/) uses tabs and suggests:

```
$('#my-tabs').tabs({
    activate: function(event, ui) {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('render');
    }
});
```

My problem is I cannot get this to work in my scenario as I am not sure where to place it - my simplified JS code is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#open").button().click(function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog("open");
    });

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        eventSources: [
            'json_feed.php'
        ]
    });

    $("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 450,
        width: 450,
        modal: false,
        activate: function(event, ui) {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('render');
        }       
    }); 
});
```

There are no errors in the console so can anyone shed any light on why this is not working?

Thanks

Comment: `dialog` doesn't have an `activate` option or event, try `open`. Creat a demo in jsfiddle.net

Comment: Created a fiddle and open has fixed it - with activate it doesn't display correctly until you resize the containing window (http://jsfiddle.net/xJ964/) but using open (http://jsfiddle.net/xJ964/1/) it works properly first time. If you want to add as an answer will accept, thanks

Comment: right...code in plugin never looks for an option `activate` in order to run it's code , so it was doing nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple issue that `jQueryUI dialog` does not have an event or option `activate`. Rather the one you want is `open`. The jQUeryUI docs for every component contain a full list of options, events, and methods with explanations and examples for all...so when in doubt start there.